# Identifying the ssh username and password on my windows machine

Tags: openssh

I am able to ssh into my windows machine but as soon as the session starts; putty asks for a username and password. how do I find/change the username and password for my windows 10 openssh feature?

Answer (score 2):

The username and password is your login credentials to the machine. the default OpenSSH on windows will not work if your login does not have a password. Either change the default OpenSSH config to work without passwords or have a login that has a password.